# Programmatic API for the Code Generators of LINQ-to-SQL and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4, code-generation, codedom

What options do I have for generating class definitions for **LINQ-to-SQL** and **Entity Framework** context and data entity objects?  I understand how to use the Visual Studio tools, but is there a programmatic API I can use to define the model and generate the corresponding code from another application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq to SQL options aren't great -- best thing I know of is [L2ST4](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) which at least gives one much more control over the generated classes. The designer document is a big, fancy XML file so I guess you could make something that generates it externally if you were so motivated.

Entity Framework has much better options -- especially since v 4.1 gives you code-first. So that means all you need to do is generate a C# class and then EF handles the rest.

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation for how the code first API works?

Comment: you could try googling for Entity Framework Code First. The very first hit takes you to the MSDN section for it.